# Trying to install less on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, less, enoent

As I wrote up there I'm trying to install less on Ubuntu. I'm using Xampp as localhost, but from what I've read seems that it doesn't matter. However, after I've installed node.js from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org), I went to [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org) and I followed the instructions.

When I type this command on the terminal

```
lessc styles.less
```

I get the following error

```
lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/cwd/styles.less'
```

where the path corresponds to my actual path but there isn't any styles.less file of course. I also tried to create a blank one and retry but nothing. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install `less` using `npm install -g less`. `lessc` should be available as `/usr/bin/lessc`.

Also, make sure `/usr/bin` is on your path by running `echo $PATH`.

*EDIT*

I just noticed you were able to run it. You need to create some `.less` files and run `lessc <FILENAME>`. The output will be printed out to the screen but you can specify a destination file as well, `lessc <SOURCE> <DESTINATION>`. See [command line usage](http://lesscss.org/usage/) I recommend using a build tool such as gulp or webpack.

Answer (score 0):

STEPS TO INSTALL LESS IN UBUNTU 16.04

1. Open Terminal.
2. Check availability of npm. Write "npm -v", here -v means version.
3. If there is npm by default in your system then it will show you the version of that npm. If there is no npm installed in your system then it will ask you to install the npm.
4. To install npm in your ubuntu. Write "sudo apt install npm".
5. Now you have to install the less library. So, to install less. Write 2 commands accordingly:-
   (i) sudo apt install less
   (ii) sudo apt install node-less